# React typescript can't get value from ref object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have got a react typescript project and have problems with login form.
Here's react login form code.

**login-form.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
    Button,
    FormGroup,
    Input,
    Label
} from 'reactstrap';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';

@observer
export class LoginForm extends React.Component {
    form: any;
    username: any;
    password: any;
    OnLogin (){
      console.log("username:",this.username);
      console.log("username value:",this.username.value);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <form className="form" ref={(form:any)=>{this.form = form}}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Label>Sign In</Label>
                    <Input type="text" name="username" ref={(username:any)=>{this.username = username}} id="username" placeholder="enter your username"/>
                    <Input type="password" name="password" ref={(password:any)=>{this.password = password}} id="password" placeholder="enter your password"/>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.OnLogin.bind(this)}>{"Login"}</Button>{' '}
                </FormGroup>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Here, when I type my username `artgb` and click on `Login` button, `OnLogin` function print this line

> username:  **Object { props: Object, context: Object, refs: Object, updater:
>   Object, _reactInternalFiber: Object, _reactInternalInstance: Object,
>   state: null }**
>
> username value:**undefined**

[image: Error Image]

I thought that username value should be `artgb` not `undefined`.

In fact I have just started typescript and can miss something basic.
Any kind of suggestion will be appreciate.

Comment: You don't need to use refs for basic forms (and it constantly baffles me how people keep coming to the conclusion they do!) - [please read the 'Forms' page in the docs for examples of the way you should do it](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html). Refs are explicitly referred to as [an escape hatch that shouldn't be overused](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value returned by the ref is a react component. So not a DOM element, for which you need to use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.username)`.
This will return the DOM element, on which you can access the value property.

But as stated by Joe Clay, you do not need the refs. Use the event as described in the links he provided.

Comment: [According to the Reactstrap docs](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/), in this case you can also access the `innerRef` prop on the React component to get the DOM element - might be a little more efficient, potentially.

Comment: Even better ! Not familiar with reactstrap, so I would not have know. :)

Comment: I got `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(username)` as input and `console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(username).nodeValue )` shows null

Comment: Replace `nodeValue` by `value` as you did before. Why do you use `nodeValue`?

Answer (score 0):

I found easy solution.

```
OnLogin (){
  let formData: any = new FormData(form);
  console.log(formData.fd.get('upload_for'));
  console.log("username:",formData.fd.get('username'));
}
```